# Ping multiple IP's at the same time

Tags: command-line, bash, ping

I have file "temp2" with for example 200 IP's.

I want to ping synchronously and save ping statistics to a file.

```
NUM=100
for a in $(seq 1 $NUM)
do
read b       
ping -s 100 -c 100 -i 1 $b | grep -Eo '([0-9]{1,10}) received.*([0-9]{1,3})% packet loss' &
done < temp2
wait
echo "all done"
```

This script starts ping in background for 100 IP's, as I understood.

How I can write ping statistics to file when ping done?

Comment: sorry,

ping -s 100 -c 100 -i 1 $b | grep -Eo '([0-9]{1,10}) received.*([0-9]{1,3})% packet loss' >> temp3 &

but I not see IP in temp3

Comment: can you please edit your question to  include this comment you just made? 
the better the question, the better the answer. Also use the code highlighting. ( {}-symbol in editor)